# EXCEPT clause in SOQL

Tags: sql, soql

I would appreciate a little help.

How do I write EXCEPT clause in Salesforce SQL?

I would like to have query which excludes rows based on a few conditions from the same database.

Like this:

```
SELECT Email_address
FROM Database_1
EXCEPT
SELECT Email_address
FROM Database_1
WHERE Brand_country = 'xyz' AND Address_country = 'abc'
```

Is there another keyword?

Or maybe is there a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `EXCEPT` isn't available you can do `NOT EXISTS` (simple), or `GROUP BY` (a little harder.)

Comment: NOT EXISTS is not simple for me. I am still figuring it out... but GROUP BY solution was just posted below. And it works like a charm. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT Email_address
FROM Database_1
GROUP BY Email_address
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Brand_country = 'xyz' AND Address_country = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```